# Identify the columns changes from two different select statement in oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, procedure

I am looking for a solution to do the below problem in Oracle SQL side.

Here is the problem statement: I have two queries which get results, and I need to compare the column values with each other and respond the column name if the value is different:

```
result1 = select id, name, address, age from Table1 where runId = 1;   
result2 = select id, name, address, age from Table1 where runId = 2;
```

I need to compare the values of `result1.name` with `result2.name`, and `result1.address` with `result2.address` ... like that only if the `result1.id = result2.id` matches and if there is any change in value (assume columns are varchar type only), then that particular column will be responded against that id.

Example:

Result1:

| id | name | address | age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | john | add-1 | 23 |
| 2 | leo | add-2 | 34 |
| 3 | paul | add-3 | 35 |

Result2:

| id | name | address | age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | john paul | add-1 | 27 |
| 2 | leo | add-2 | 39 |

Output

| id | columnName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | name |
| 1 | age |
| 2 | age |

Note: if single query cannot be possible to achieve above logic, then an Oracle procedure can be acceptable by returning the above format. In place of name, address, age, there can more columns needs to compare in real query hence performance should not be compromised as the number of rows can be millions of record here. If parallel processing in Oracle can be used here then it would be great.

Comment: Is the number of columns fixed and clearly known, or are you looking for a generic solution for any table?

Comment: The number of columns from both results will be always same and fixed

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
with q as (
  select coalesce(a.id, b.id) as id,
    a.name as aname, a.address as aaddress, a.age as aage,
    b.name as bname, b.address as baddress, b.age as bage
  from result1 a
  full join result2 b on b.id = a.id -- remove "full" for simpler comparison
)
select id, 'name' as column_name from q where decode(aname, bname, 1, 0) = 0
union all
select id, 'address' from q where decode(aaddress, baddress, 1, 0) = 0
union all
select id, 'age' from q where decode(aage, bage, 1, 0) = 0
order by id, 2;
```

Result:

```
 ID  COLUMN_NAME 
 --- ----------- 
 1   age         
 1   name        
 2   age         
 3   address     
 3   age         
 3   name
```

And:

```
 ID  COLUMN_NAME 
 --- ----------- 
 1   age         
 1   name        
 2   age
```

Respectively. See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/gpwhInre).

Comment: Since id 3 doesnt exist in Result2 , then it should not return. How to modify the above query for that?

Comment: See comment in line #6.

Comment: Here Result1 and Result2 are not seperate tables. These are results from the query which I mentioned in the question for the different runKey in the same table.

Comment: You can replace `result1` by `(<query1>)` and `result2` by `(<query2>)`.

Comment: What about the performance for this query? Will it execute faster for millions of records or any scope for optimization

Comment: For performance concerns plase ask a separate question. It's a different topic. You would need to include the exact query and the execution plan.